# Why is it possible to store more than one characters in a "char" variable?

Tags: c, char

This is a practice quiz question:

```
int main()
{
    char ch = '\060';
    printf("%d\n", ch+1);
    return 0;
}    // What is the output?
```

And the answer was `49`.

I think it's `49` because a `0` is `48` on the ASCII table, and 48 + 1 = 49. Is `60` ignored/disregarded (`ch` is a char variable, not a string one)? Also, I thought `\0` represented a null character at first, so I thought the output was `1` (null characters have a value of `0` on the ASCII table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\060'` is a single character, in which `060` are octal digits, whose value is indeed `48` in decimal.

> #### C11 §6.4.4.4 Character constants
>
> ```
> octal-escape-sequence:
>
> \ octal-digit
> \ octal-digit octal-digit
> \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`'\060'` represents a *single character*, not a string (single quotes).  It's a literal for the character encoded with the *octal* value `060`, or decimal `48` (ASCII character `'0'`).  Adding one to that value gives you decimal `49` (ASCII character `'1'`).

Answer (score 0):

`\060` would be recognized as an octal digits and thus equal to 48 in decimal. As a char variable, it equals to '0' in ASCII. However, as the output format is `%d`, it doesn't make much sense what the ASCII character is.